# Add a custom button/ tag and control its function using a python script in Django web application

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am quite new to web application development (Django). However, I have a bit of experience in working with html, css, and  python.
I am developing an application where the ***user will upload documents as input and change the available parameters values and the application will generate a new document*** as a downloadable file. (Text editor: *VS Code*).
(*To get an intuition, consider the online pdf resizing applications as an example*).

I am building the application from scratch. The major issue is modifying the inputs and producing desired output.
My approach towards it is:

1. Create python scripts for the different major actions( As per our example case, create `pdf_compression.py`, `merge_two_pdfs.py` and so on).
2. Ask the user to upload the required documents. Store the docs uploaded (only temporarily) and use them for further operations (*with assumption that default sqlite3 will be sufficient*).
3. In the webpage, add a button or a link (e.g. "`Compress`", "`Merge`") and embed the python script created in step1 (*paste the script or add a link to its file location*). That will perform the specific task when the button is pressed and generate the output.
4. Download the generated document.

I have achieved till the step 2 in my task but am lost on how to achieve the "3rd" step. How should I proceed  ahead?
Any suggestions( with code examples) are highly appreciated. I am open to any different approach also.

**Update**
**About the application**
The application does not need to serve users globally like google. It will be hosted through a server locally( or though an institutions' local server) and users having access to the server will be accessing it.(in other words it does not need to be `https://www...` It only needs to be `http://ip_address/url`.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A web browser runs JavaScript scripts, so your python script will not run on the client side

Comment: @rioV8 Isn't there any way I can achieve it with python scripts? Would including the scripts as functions in the html page itself work? I had an impression that the script could be called like an html page refers to a css document using <link href = "{%static% 'filename.css'}"/>.  By the way, the application will be hosted through the server locally only. It is not required for the users globally

Comment: You are looking for the term `ajax`, make an ajax request using JavaScript and have a view that will run those scripts of yours. (You should easily be able to find tutorials, examples, etc. now that you know the technology you need to use)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks, I will look into it. Using ajax, will I be able to implement those py scripts? I have spent a fare amount of time creating them for the purpose and don't want them to go in waste.

Comment: A bit of research before asking will do you good, people on Stack Overflow like well researched questions :). If you check what ajax is it simply is making a request to the server behind the scenes, so yes you can run any code on the server you want by calling / writing them into the views...

Comment: 'views` is another term for `request-handler`, for people stuck on one particular framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to embed your python scripts anywhere (or to use any javascript/AJAX, as some of the comments suggest).  The simplest way to do "step 3" is as follows:

- When the "Compress"/"Merge" button (or link) is pressed, send a request to the server.  Typically you'd use the URL to indicate which action(s) to perform.
- When the server receives the above request, generate the corresponding output file.  Any scripts that are installed on the server can be used to help make this file.  That said, I would recommend against writing separate scripts for each task.  Better would be to simply include the processing functions in your django application so the server can call them directly, without having to go through a command-line interface.  Or, if the functions would also be useful outside the context of a web server, they can be moved into their own general-purpose package.
- Save the generated file to the database.  This isn't necessary if the server will always run on just one machine, but it's still a good idea if for no other reason than making your code more future-proof.
- Create a URL that will serve the generated output file to the client.
- Present the user with a download link to the aforementioned URL.

In short, do all the processing on the server.

---

You may already be aware of this, but one concern with sqlite is that it does not allow more than one process to access the database at a time (roughly speaking).  So if there's any possibility that two people will be using your website simultaneously, don't assume that sqlite will be sufficient.

Comment: Please clarify `I would recommend against writing separate scripts for each task`.  Are you implying that I should merge all the scripts in one and modify them such that they will output different outputs when different tasks are requested?  but each task is different. **e.g.** task2 needs the output of task1 but task2 should execute only after the user requests for it.

Comment: I would recommend writing them as separate functions.  So instead of writing a script called `pdf_compression.py` and calling it from python via `subprocess.run(['pdf_compression.py, ...])`, just add a function to your django app called `def pdf_compression(): ...` that can be called directly.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I have accepted the answer. Initially I was quite confused with where to use my custom functions since we have so many elements interlinked e.g. forms, views, templates, etc. Things are much clearer now. Btw, (a small query) is there any way I can work with the user uploaded files without having to save them at _media root or database_ permanently? e.g. the user file gets stored in a temp. location and gets deleted after some time interval. I played around with `form.save()`  but no luck.

Comment: Glad you got it to work!  You might be able to get the kind of temporary behavior you want using [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/).  Sessions still use the database behind the scenes, though.  The reason is that the request to generate the file and the request to serve the file might be handled by different processes/servers, so the database is the only reliable way to share information.